# link to "#" - strange behavior

Tags: http, url, browser

First, I create a link to the url `#`.

When I hover over the link, I see the browser turns it into `http://[current url]/raw#`.

Here is the strange part.  I click the button to increment the counter. Then I click the link.  My browser's `back` button shows my location has changed.  But the counter state is preserved!

[This example shows the behavior.](http://share-elm.com/sprout/52a9ec1fe4b06194fd2d331d/stable/view)

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shown here [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp) This is a **bookmark** feature of links. It doesn't exactly pull a new page , just navigates within the current page.

Forward and back still preserve the path but the entire page isn't refreshed.

Comment: Thanks!  So I guess a `#` without anything after it defaults to the top of the page.